# Update Passbook Error - The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid

Tags: php, ios, passbook, wallet

I'm trying to send a new pass json data to my device to update my pass in Apple Wallet following the part "Getting the Latest Version of a Pass" in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988). 
The new json data is exactly the same the json data that I used for creating the pass successfully, except the backgroundColor is changed from #3e7cc8 to #000000 (for testing) but I got the "Invalid json data" error all the time. 
Here are the successful creating json data

```
{
   "description":"description",
   "formatVersion":1,
   "organizationName":"organizationName",
   "passTypeIdentifier":"passTypeIdentifier",
   "serialNumber":"serialNumber",
   "teamIdentifier":"teamIdentifier",
   "foregroundColor":"#ffffff",
   "backgroundColor":"#3e7cc8",
   "labelColor":"#ffffff",
   "barcode":{
      "message":"d568866a45dfc010ac680a9d06e5a48feb9216a2",
      "messageEncoding":"utf-8",
      "format":"PKBarcodeFormatQR"
   },
   "logoText":"logoText",
   "storeCard":{
      "headerFields":[

      ],
      "primaryFields":[

      ],
      "secondaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"name",
            "label":"",
            "value":"Nick"
         },
         {
            "key":"points",
            "label":"",
            "value":"0 Points"
         }
      ],
      "auxiliaryFields":[

      ],
      "backFields":[
         {
            "key":"email",
            "label":"Email",
            "value":"hoangtrung.uit@gmail.com"
         },
         {
            "key":"phone",
            "label":"Phone",
            "value":"+841689984964"
         }
      ],
      "locations":[

      ]
   },
   "authenticationToken":"authenticationToken",
   "webServiceURL":"https://mydomain/passbook"
}
```

and the invalid updating json data

```
{
   "description":"description",
   "formatVersion":1,
   "organizationName":"organizationName",
   "passTypeIdentifier":"passTypeIdentifier",
   "serialNumber":"serialNumber",
   "teamIdentifier":"teamIdentifier",
   "foregroundColor":"#ffffff",
   "backgroundColor":"#000000",
   "labelColor":"#ffffff",
   "barcode":{
      "message":"d568866a45dfc010ac680a9d06e5a48feb9216a2",
      "messageEncoding":"utf-8",
      "format":"PKBarcodeFormatQR"
   },
   "logoText":"logoText",
   "storeCard":{
      "headerFields":[

      ],
      "primaryFields":[

      ],
      "secondaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"name",
            "label":"",
            "value":"Nick"
         },
         {
            "key":"points",
            "label":"",
            "value":"0 Points"
         }
      ],
      "auxiliaryFields":[

      ],
      "backFields":[
         {
            "key":"email",
            "label":"Email",
            "value":"hoangtrung.uit@gmail.com"
         },
         {
            "key":"phone",
            "label":"Phone",
            "value":"+841689984964"
         }
      ],
      "locations":[

      ]
   },
   "authenticationToken":"authenticationToken",
   "webServiceURL":"https://mydomain/passbook"
}
```

What's wrong with my updating json data? Please help.

Comment: If you attempt to open the pass on an iOS device, the logging (from XCode, for example) will usually tell you the exact issue.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness The pass is created successfully. I run into the problem when I'm trying to send update json data following "Getting the Latest Version of a Pass" in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)

Comment: iOS will still output logging indicating why the update has failed. When you sent the push notification, iOS should walk through the process of polling your API and reporting what it's doing.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness Ok, I see. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you have no success, send the pass to me and I'll see what logging comes out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the only thing that has changed is the backgroundColor, then it suggests a manifest/signing issue or omission of an icon image in your updated bundle.  May be worth unzipping the updated bundle ands double checking it contains what you think it should contain.

There is a chance that #000000 causes an edge case (as it is equal to zero), but this could be ruled out with a quick test of a different test value like #ff0000.

As Thomas has stated in the comments, the Device logs in Xcode should tell you the exact reason for the failure.

Comment: I'm wondering, do we need to return a pass bundle or just pass json data?

Comment: You need to return a new, full, signed pass bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW5) states:

> Background color of the pass, specified as an CSS-style RGB triple. For example, rgb(23, 187, 82)

You can try to follow the format given by the documentation.

Comment: But it's created successfully with "backgroundColor":"#3e7cc8". Anw, I'll try to change it to an CSS-style RGB triple. Thanks.